# Format date and add month to it

Tags: date, c++builder

I'm currently working with embarcadero c++, this is the first time I'm working with it so it's completely new to me.

What I'm trying to achieve is to get the current date, make sure the date has the `"dd/MM/yyyy"` format. When I'm sure this is the case I want to add a month to the current date.

So let's say the current date is 08/18/2016 this has to be changed to 18/08/2016 and then the end result should be 18/09/2016.

I've found that there is a method for [this](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.SysUtils.IncAMonth) in embarcardero however I'm not sure how to use this.

currently I've only been able to get the current date like this.

```
TDateTime currentDate = Date();
```

I hope someone will be able to help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

A date object doesn't have a format like "dd/MM/yyyy". A date object is internally simply represented as a number (or possibly some other form of representation that really isn't your problem or responsibility).

So you don't have to check if it's in this format because no date objects will ever be in this format, they simply don't have a format.

You will have to do additions/subtractions on the Date object that the language or library gives you, THEN (optionally) you can format it to a human-readable string so it looks like 18/08/2016 or 18th of August 2016 or whatever other readable format that you choose.

It might be that the TRANSFER of a date between 2 systems is in a similar format, but then formatting the date like that is entirely up to you.

As for how to do that, the link you posted seems like a possible way (or alternatively http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.SysUtils.IncMonth), I'm afraid I can't give you an example as I'm not familiar with the tool/language involved, I'm just speaking generically about Date manipulations and they should ALWAYS be on the raw object.

Comment: I would like to try the `IncMonth` then however I don't know how to use the code they provided since I have zero experience with c++. Could you possibly give me an example? I tried adding the `extern` part at the top of the file however this would just give me an error.

Comment: Sorry C++ has been too long for me, more than 10 years for sure. Maybe someone else will have a concrete example.

Comment: the problem with the date is that I need to be sure that it will be dd/MM/yyyy because I'm sending the information to a magento backend which needs to be able to set a certain value at the exact day. So what I want it to keep it a date format and just make sure that the days come in front of the months

Comment: I tried explaining this in my post a bit more. Simply put: a date object doesn't have a format like dd/MM/yyyy.

Comment: but if I converted it to a string with this format and then converted it back to a date would it then be in the desired format or would it take the system format(which it is doing now) when converted back

Comment: Again, nothing in a date object has a format. There might be a default ToString or default formatting if you look at the date while debugging, but that doesn't mean the date has a format.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121245/discussion-between-nosixties-and-sebastiaan-van-den-broek).

Comment: Formatting a `TDateTime` to a `String` is done using the `TDateTime::FormatString()` method or the `FormatDateTime()` function. Both allow you to specify custom formatting, like "MM/DD/YYYY" vs "DD/MM/YYYY".

Comment: Date objects have a format (like anything else has). Internally, it is a Double containing date in the integral part (number of days since a special date).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis obviously. Read the first paragraph of my answer. Btw it's not the amount of days that is stored.

Comment: @Sebastiaan: Yes, it is. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.TDateTime. TDate is a TDateTime with a fractional part of 0.

Comment: Oh yeah you're right, I'm used to them just storing the epoch value.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

After I've searched some more I found the way to use the `IncMonth` method on [this](http://www.functionx.com/cppbuilder/topics/datetime.htm) page.

The example given my problem is as follows:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::edtMonthsExit(TObject *Sender)
{
    TDateTime StartDate = edtStartDate->Text;
    int Months = edtMonths->Text.ToInt();
    TDateTime NextPeriod = IncMonth(StartDate, Months);
    edtNextPeriod->Text = NextPeriod;
}
```

After looking at I changed my code accordingly to this

```
TDateTime CurrentDate = Date();
TDateTime EndDate = IncMonth(CurrentDate, 1);
```